# Problem in converting functional component to class component (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

This is my functional component. Works fine

---

```
    import React from "react";

    function RecommendationCard(props) {
      const { name, designation, company, message } = props.recommendation;
      return (
        <div className="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div className="card shadow h-100">
            <div className="card-body">
              <h4 className="card-text">{message}</h4>
              <p className="card-text text-secondary mb-0">{name}</p>
              <p className="card-text text-secondary">
                {designation} at {company}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default RecommendationCard;
```

The below code is converted state component.Here intead of using props , I used the data from my context.js file  like state. It contains all the data like name,company,designation,recommendation. So I'm using it through the consumer . But that is not displaying the properties.

---

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { Consumer } from '../context';

  class RecommendationCardextends Component {
    state = {
      name:"",
      message:"",
      designation:"",
      company:"",
    }

      render() {
        return(
          <Consumer>
          {(value) =>{
              const { name, designation, company,message } = this.state;
              
              return (
                <div className="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div className="card shadow h-100">
                  <div className="card-body">
                    <h4 className="card-text">{message}</h4>
                    <p className="card-text text-secondary mb-0">{name}</p>
                    <p className="card-text text-secondary">
                      {designation} at {company}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              );
          }}
        </Consumer>
        );
    }
  }
    
  
  export default RecommendationCard;
```

I request you to please solve this and help me out with this. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Just like you said, `Context` holds all your data, but you are destructuring it from `this.state`, which is the local state of your component.

Answer (score 0):

I made a working example on codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-chatelet-7il42?file=/src/App.js

App:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import RecommendationCard from "./components/RecommendationCard";
import {MyContext} from "./context"

const initialState = {
  message: "default message",
  company: "default company",
  designation: "default designation",
  name: "default name"
};

export { MyContext };

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyContext.Provider value={initialState}>
        <RecommendationCard />
      </MyContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

RecommendationCard:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MyContext } from "../context";

class RecommendationCard extends Component {
  
  static contextType = MyContext;

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div className="card shadow h-100">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h4 className="card-text">{this.context.message}</h4>
            <p className="card-text text-secondary mb-0">{this.context.name}</p>
            <p className="card-text text-secondary">
              {this.context.designation} at {this.context.company}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RecommendationCard;
```

context:

```
import React from "react";

export const MyContext = React.createContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern!  Attempted import error: 'Context' is not exported from '../context'.

Comment: I made a working answer on codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-chatelet-7il42?file=/src/components/RecommendationCard.js

Comment: Thank you! Coud you look in to this. https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-buck-1dvev?file=/src/index.js

Comment: It looks ok from a glance, but I can't run it without the rest of the import files. Its also recommended by the official React docs to export the Context itself rather than the Context.Consumer. Since you're using functional components, you can import the Context and deconstruct it with a useContext hook: const { handler, blogs } = useEffect(Context). If you do it that way, there is no need for a Consumer or {value => } syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```js
      <Consumer>
        {({ name, designation, company, message }) => (
          <div className="col-12 col-md-4">
            <div className="card shadow h-100">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="card-text">{message}</h4>
                <p className="card-text text-secondary mb-0">{name}</p>
                <p className="card-text text-secondary">
                  {designation} at {company}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Consumer>
```

Assuming you don't intend to do anything with it going forward, your local state would be obsolete in the example you provided. All your data is inside `value`. I personally feel this becomes much easier when using the Hook API [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: Thanks for your concern! But in the output, These values are not displaying (name,company,designation,message.). Instead at is printed in the output

Comment: is `RecommendationCard` wrapped in a `Provider`? It should look something like this `<MyContext.Provider value={/* some value */}>`. The `value` prop holds your data and your `Consumer` gives you access to that object via the so called render prop pattern. Can you provide a codesandbox for us to look at?

Comment: My apologies for the delay! Here's my codesandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-buck-1dvev?file=/src/index.js